# How could I go about appending array elements to an array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

For example, let's say I have the following:

```js
let data = [{name: "Bob"}, {name: "Alice"}]
let numArr = [12, 34]
```

I'd like this as the result:

```js
let newData = [{name: "Bob", number: 12}, {name: "Alice", number: 34}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const 
  data = [{name: "Bob"}, {name: "Alice"}],
  numArr = [12, 34];

const newData = data.map((e, i) => ({ ...e, number: numArr[i] }));

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator#alternative_iteration) and `forEach`.

```js
let data = [{name: "Bob"}, {name: "Alice"}];
let numArr = [12, 34];

ns=numArr[Symbol.iterator]();
data.forEach((d)=>d.number=ns.next().value);

document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

You need to define the iterated array outside of the `forEach` loop, otherwise the definition is re-initiated with every pass, and returns the same value each time.